# Look at the first letter of each string in an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, charat

I am trying to assess weather any word in a user input string starts with an "@".

Ive started by breaking the input string into an array of words.
Then loop through each word looking at the first letter to see if its an "@".

I cant figure out why charAt() seems to be returning an error.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<input id="txt" type="textarea" />
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>



<script>
function myFunction (){
  var text = document.getElementById('txt').value;
  var inputArray = [text.split(" ")];
  console.log(inputArray);

  for(i=0; i < inputArray.length; i++){
    console.log(inputArray[i]);
    if(inputArray[i].charAt(0) === '@'){
      console.log("its an at symbol");
    } else{
      console.log("nope");
    }
  }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `text.split(" ")` already returns an array. Why are you wrapping it in one?

Comment: `const symbols = text.match(/@\w+/) || [];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `var inputArray = [text.split(" ")];` seems to be the culprit. `text.split(" ")` will return an array, so by wrapping that statement in brackets, you're getting an array whose first index is the array you're looking for.

Therefore `inputArray[i]` in the for loop is actually looking to perform `charAt(0)` on an array of strings, not a string itself.

Comment: Thanks man! That totally makes sense and worked. I thought that it needed to be explicitly put into an array.

Comment: No problem! Glad to help.